# How to disable the insertion point (cursor in textfield when typing) in iOS TexfField? (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

I was looking everywhere, but I can not find an answer. I have a textfield and I want it to be invisble. That means hiding the insertion point as well.

Comment: `textfield.enabled = false`

Comment: your question will not give you any help, provide some code. Basically textField.hidden = true; should do the trick

Comment: @Bannings if I disable the textfield it does not work, but I need it to work :/

Comment: @Basheer_CAD I do not know what code would help clarify my question. If I hide it, it is not there and usable as well so that would not help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using `.tintColor` and `.textColor` and setting both to `UIColor().clearColor()` works as intended.